# Java - Seat Reservation system

Tags: java, sql, database

I need to create a reservation system that will reserved seats for one or many passenger
If for example the passenger reserved for three seats how can I make the three of those reserved seats be inserted into one auto incrementing id in my database?

For example if passenger reserve for three seats, in my database it should look like:

```
Ticket Number   Passenger Name        
2               passenger1
2               passenger2
2               passenger3
```

This is what I'm using now:

```
sql1 = "INSERT INTO  passenger_details(fname,lname,gender,address,cc_no,bank_name,no_of_tickets,seat,destination)  
VALUES('"+fnm+"','"+lnm+"','"+gnd+"','"+add+"','"+cc+"','"+bank+"','"+tckts+"','"+seats+"','"+dest+"')
('"+fnm+"','"+lnm+"','"+gnd+"','"+add+"','"+cc+"','"+bank+"','"+tckts+"','"+seats2+"','"+dest+"'), 
('"+fnm+"','"+lnm+"','"+gnd+"','"+add+"','"+cc+"','"+bank+"','"+tckts+"','"+seats3+"','"+dest+"')";
```

Comment: Better start using `PreparedStatement` or I'll introduce you to my friend [bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @alfasin: As much as I love xkcd, [this link](http://bobby-tables.com/) also has solutions, not just the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a separate `reservations` table with `passenger_id` and `seat_no` columns. This will reduce the duplicated information.

Also, when you are actually inserting the reservations, you probably need to use a for loop since you don't know before hand exactly how many seats will be reserved by a single customer.

Finally, you need to be aware of SQL Injection attacks. Your current implementation is very unsafe as others have pointed out in the comments.